# Sending values from radio button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I am working on a website that has a sort of quiz in it. What I am currently trying to do is have a value be sent to my function when I hit submit and if it is 0 then write "false" and if it is 1 then write "pass". I wrote the JavaScript but it does not work and I am unsure why. The write to HTML event is firing when I hit the radio button which I assume is because of the onclick I have for it. I don't know how to send the value without it though and if that would fix the issue. I also know that the program is only writing false no matter what I click instead of "pass" for no and "false" for yes. When I press the submit button it doesn't work right. The false/pass shouldn't appear until it is pressed but instead when I press the submit button It will change "false" to "pass". I don't know how to fix any of this or why it is doing this.

Thank you for the help let me know if more clarification is needed.

This is my HTML

```
            <body>
             <form id="myForm">
         <div class="sub form-row align-items-center">
             <div class="col">
            <fieldset>
                <h3><legend>Eligibility Test</legend></h3>
            </fieldset>
             </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col">
               <fieldset>
                   <div class="col">
                <legend>Have you had your record expunged before?</legend>
                  <input type="radio" name="field1" id="field1" value="0" onclick="getscores1()"/>
                     <label>
                     Yes
                </label>
                    <input type="radio" name="field1" id="field1" value="1" onclick="getscores1()"/>
                 <label>
                     No
                </label>
                </fieldset>
             </div>
             <div class="col">
             <div class="row">
                 <fieldset>
                <legend>Do you have any charges pending against you?</legend>
                  <input type="radio" name="field2" id="field2 value="0" onclick="getscores2()"/>
                     <label>
                     Yes
                </label>
                       <input type="radio" name="field2" id="field2 value="1" onclick="getscores2()"/>
                 <label>
                     No
                </label>
            </fieldset>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <fieldset id="submitbutton">
                 <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" 
             onclick='answer()' />
            </fieldset>
             <p id="totalScore">this is answer </p>
```

This is my JavaScript

```
             <script>
             function getscores1(){
             score1= document.getElementById('field1').value;
             answer(score1);
             }
             function answer(score1){
             if (score1 == 0 ){
             document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "false";
             }
             else{
             document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "pass";
             }
             }

             </script>
```

Comment: Can you please separate your HTML and your JavaScript? this is really difficult to read through

Comment: "I don't know how to send the value without it though". Forget about _sending_ values. When you run the "answer" method, it doesn't need any input parameters. Group your radio buttons, then let your "answer" function find the selected radio from each group, and read the value of that button. Currently you have a problem when you click the "submit" button because you don't pass any value for "score1", so it can't execute the `if` statement as expected, since that parameter is null.

Comment: @ADyson I thought I was passing the score1 to answer with the 
        "answer(score1)" I used at the bottom of getscore1 and the parameter of answer?

Comment: When the radiobutton changes yes you do that, but not when you call `onclick='answer()'`. And obviously this runs the logic again and over-writes anything which happened the previous time(s) you ran it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working for the following reasons:

- You're missing a `</div>` before `</fieldset>`
- You have duplicate IDs (2 `field1` and 2 `field2`)
- Your duplicate `field2` IDs are both missing the closing quotation mark

Considering you're not allowed duplicate IDs, I recommend removing those. As you're calling the function on click of both radio buttons, instead of using IDs, you can actually just pass through the element itself to the function with the **[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)** operator as `onclick="getscores1(this)"`.

Then you just have to adapt your function to take the argument as a function parameter:

```
function getscores1(score1) {
  answer(score1.value);
}
```

This can be seen working in the following example:

```js
function getscores1(score1) {
  answer(score1.value);
}

function answer(score1) {
  if (score1 == 0) {
    document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "false";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "pass";
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <div class="sub form-row align-items-center">
      <div class="col">
        <fieldset>
          <h3>
            <legend>Eligibility Test</legend>
          </h3>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="col">
          <legend>Have you had your record expunged before?</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="field1" value="0" onclick="getscores1(this)" />
          <label>
            Yes
          </label>
          <input type="radio" name="field1" value="1" onclick="getscores1(this)" />
          <label>
            No
          </label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Do you have any charges pending against you?</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="field2" value=" 0 " onclick="getscores2(this)" />
          <label>
            Yes
          </label>
          <input type="radio" name="field2 " value="1" onclick="getscores2(this)" />
          <label>
            No
          </label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset id="submitbutton">
      <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick='answer()' />
    </fieldset>
    <p id="totalScore">this is answer </p>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: onclick='answer()' still doesn't make much sense, and it crashes if you press the second set of radios (getScores2 doesn't exist).